# how to get order numbers greater than an order id?

Tags: grid, sales

how to add a filter so that I can get order numbers greater than a number? I can show them in descending order but I want to show just the latest orders from an order number until the end

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection') ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', array('gt' => $value);

gt converts to increment_id > $value
```

You get a problem when you have different websites and therefore different number circles...